# Change maximumBillingTier for BigQuery API?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently running a query that requires billing tier 4. When running my post request to the query endpoint, I'm setting `"maximumBillingTier":4`. I'm able to run the query successfully within the BigQuery console but not from my actual application with the API. My projects default billing tier is Tier 1.

Comment: it is hard to help without seeing your code

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I'm not referring to code specifically. I'm referring more to if there is a way to change the billing tier for my project, the code implementation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is a way to change the billing tier for my project

You can submit the BigQuery [High-Compute queries form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/bigquery_high_compute_queries_quota_request_form) to set a project-wide default

> Update:

As per [`November 14, 2017 Release Notes`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#november_14_2017) -

> > High compute queries are being phased out so you are no longer required to opt-in. All high compute queries under tier 100 are billed as tier 1. Running a high compute query does not require setting a threshold flag.
> >
> > All queries above tier 100 will fail with a RESOURCES_EXCEEDED_PER_BYTE error unless the query is running in a reserved instance. Existing users who have run a high compute query higher than tier 100 in the last 30 days retain the ability to run queries at the higher billing tier until October 31, 2018.

Comment: Sadly this from does not exist anymore. I was hoping that could be the answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48410977/changing-project-tier-using-web-ui question. Is there an updated form to request a different billing tier?

Comment: @Rotkiv - thank you for pinging  - I updated answer as it gets outdated