# Changing project tier using web UI?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Two questions:

- Can I change my Tier using Web UI?
- And, more generally, what is "Tier"?
- What is the relation between "Tier" and "pricing" ?

---

*Context*

I am trying to execute a query but getting the following error:

> Error: Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 292 or higher
>   required. (error code: billingTierLimitExceeded)

It is a resource intense query, but it is not a large job. According to bq:

> Valid: This query will process 433 MB when run.

BQ Documentation mentions Billing Tier in the [JOBS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.maximumBillingTier) section.
But I am not sure how to adjust Tier when using WebUI.

---

error code:billingTierLimitExceeded is not described on [Troubleshooting Errors page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#billingTierLimitExceeded)

I have checked every conceivable corner of my GCP console (api, quotas etc) and could not find anything that would indicate that I am hitting a limit on my account.

Pricing page does not list anything about Tiers and how to switch Tiers.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in November, Google announced that they were phasing out the opt-in billing tier for high-compute queries. All queries under 100 are now billed at 1. As such, they've removed the billing tier option from the UI. You can read more about it here in the [release](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#november_14_2017) notes. I'd strongly recommended reviewing your query and tweaking it to improve performance. You'd be surprised that just a few small changes as per the BigQuery best practices can have a significant impact on the billing tier.